# How to enumerate all files in all subdirectories Obj-C/Obj-C++/Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c++, macos-sierra

Well, I've asked what could be called a similar question but no one provided even a slightly detailed answer or any context as to the commands proper syntax so I'll change the question a bit. I need a way to enumerate all the files in all sub-directories of a specifiable directory, load the result to a variable, and then write that variable to a file, appending a tail to the end of the file.

Some people have asked how to do this with particular mime-types or extensions, but I need a way to do this with no discrimination or regard for the contents of the file or it's extension. I need a Cocoa compatible way to do this in Objective-C or Objective-C++.

For example if I had the directory structure:

```
/Foo/
     ->bar.txt
     ->foobar/
              ->flurp.mp3
              ->foop.list
     ->emptydir/
     ->afile.css
```

I would need it to return the following to a variable so it could be written to a file:

```
/Foo/bar.txt
/Foo/foobar/flurp.mp3
/Foo/foobar/foop.list
/Foo/afile.css
```

*Notice that it skips `/Foo/emptydir/` in the list as I only want it to list the full path of files in the directories, and ignore the directories themselves.

BTW I am doing this on macOS Sierra in XCode 8.0 in case that effects the syntax of the commands.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `NSFileManager`?

Comment: @maddy Yes, I attempted to copy-paste an example from Apple's documentation to get a feel for each component of a proper function utilizing it (obviously replacing placeholder variables with actual content) and it kicked up something like 14 errors in Playground, and there wasn't enough context to troubleshoot the errors. A lot of examples of what commands and types were available with NSTask and NSFileManager, but not enough direct examples of how to use them to actually determine it's proper syntax.

Comment: Do you mean the Swift playground? Are you trying to paste Objective-C code into the Swift playground? That isn't going to work too well.

Comment: @maddy It was an example for the Swift version of `NSFileManager`: `FileManager`. I had originally built the application with Swift, and eventually rebuilt it in Obj-C in an attempt to be able to call C++ functions (I am trying to port several C++ terminal utilities I made to a singular Cocoa GUI based app where they can be called as applets.), but in the end that didn't work out either. I am pretty much at a loss as to what to do besides try again with Swift and recreate the C++ functions using the obscene quantity of code required to preform the same task in Swift.